# Como não perder a session de uma aba para outra?

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando criar um login no qual após validar que o usuário e senha estão corretos crie na sessionStorage a seguinte variavel:

`sessionStorage.setItem('ClienteId', resp.ClienteId);`

Fazendo assim com que ao entrar em cada page eu verifico antes se existe o cliente na session, mas ao mudar de aba perco a mesma. Teria como trabalhar sem perdê-la?

Ou alguma forma melhor de realizar o login? Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso você pode usar o [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage), onde poderá ser compartilhado entre as abas do browser.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que usando o sessionStorage é uma boa opção, visto que esse não realizará a persistência dos dados, enquanto o localStorage o fará.

Ou seja, se você reiniciar o navegador por exemplo, os dados do sessionStorage serão apagados(não-persistente), enquanto os dados permanecerão no localStorage.

Aí vai da sua necessidade. Acredito no seu caso, por se tratar de um ID de cliente, o interessante é 'sumir' com ele quando você fechar o navegador, então sessionStorage mesmo.

Comment: Utilizei o LocalStorage mesmo realizando um session abandon caso saia da page ou peça para deslogar!